# Change Desktop directory

Tags: home-directory, desktop-background, xdg

I would like to temporarily use a different directory as my "Desktop". Is there a way to do this?

Would it be possible to have different wallpapers for each directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which directory is used as your Desktop is configured in the simple text file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, which looks like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

To set a different directory as your desktop, just edit the line starting with `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=` to your needs.

After that you must restart the Nautilus daemon process which is responsible for displaying the desktop icons for the changes to take effect. This can be done by simply logging out and back in, or by running this command below (which will also close all open File Manager windows):

```
(nautilus --quit && nautilus --no-default-window & disown) &> /dev/null
```

This all is unrelated to your desktop background wallpaper though, so unless you change it manually every time, it will stay the same.